# where to return value from a recursive function in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using recursive function to get values out of database, but in my code I get only first record as return. Where should I put return to return function after everything completes?

```
function sidebar_sub_sub($id)
{
    $sql="select subcatagory_id,subcatagory_name,haschild,parent from subcatagory where parent=".$id."";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    $resultset=array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($query))
        {
            while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {     
                array_push($resultset,$result);
                if($result['haschild'])
                {
                    $sb=sidebar_sub_sub($result['subcatagory_id']);
                }             

            }

        }
        return $resultset;            
}
```

Comment: To understand recursion you need to understand recursion first! Oh, and trust, me, you **do not want to send database queries in recursive functions or loops**!

Answer (score 0):

you store the result of `sidebar_sub_sub()` in $sb. But then you do nothing with this variable.

You could do a `array_push($resultset, sidebar_sub_sub())` instead. This way you return the whole stack of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script that i used for my categories table in which there are just three fields id, name and parent_id. It may work for you.

```
$resultset=array();
function sidebar_sub_sub($id)
{
    global $resultset;
    $sql="select id,name,parent_id from categories where parent_id=".$id."";    
    $query=mysql_query($sql);

    if(mysql_num_rows($query))
    {
        while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {   
            array_push($resultset,$result);            
            if($result['parent_id']>0){
                sidebar_sub_sub($result['id']);
            }
        }

    }
    return $resultset; 
}
$result = sidebar_sub_sub(1);
```

Comment: @RamilAmr can you please suggest other way of achieving the solution for above question?