# Combine Two Queries

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am currently using the following two queries:

```
$get_forum=$this->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_PREFIX."forums WHERE id=:forum_id");
$get_forum->bindParam(":forum_id", $forum_id);
$get_forum->execute();

$forum=$get_forum->fetchAll();

$get_parent=$this->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_PREFIX."forums WHERE id=:parent_id");
$get_parent->bindParam(":parent_id", $forum["parent_id"]);
$get_parent->execute();
```

I would like to combine them into one query something like this where it uses the bound param or a value from a field in the database. I don't know what the parent ID is until I get the forum data back from the database.

Parent forums have a parent_id of -1, while child forums have the parent_id set to the id of the parent.

```
$get_forums=$this->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_PREFIX."forums WHERE id=:forum_id OR forum_id=parent_id");
$get_forums->bindParam(":forum_id", $forum_id);
$get_forums->execute();
```

Is it possible to use a field value while inside the query itself to compare it with another value?

Database sample:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b354/1

Comment: Yes, you can compare values in a single row of data.

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a self-join:

```
SELECT *
FROM   forums parent JOIN forums child ON parent.forum_id = child.parent_id
WHERE  parent.id = ? OR child.id = ?
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it only gave me back one row the child row and not both child and parents row.

Comment: I also tried this:
"SELECT *
FROM   forums parent JOIN forums child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
WHERE  parent.id = child.parent_id OR child.id = :forum_id"


However that gave me two child rows and no parent row.

Comment: I've never used that site before but here goes:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6786e/9

'Cars' is the parent forum of 'Supercars'. Parent forums have a parent_id of -1, while child forums have the parent_id set to the id of the parent.

Comment: My knowledge of sql is a bit limited how would a union look in this case?

Comment: No, the linked word `UNION` in my comment above.

Comment: I had a look at your example but there is a problem. It hardsets parent_id to 1. Parent id can vary and I need to base it off a field from the first part of the union.

Comment: And, to be clear, given a record's ID you're trying to fetch that record together with all of its children?

Comment: Nope. I am getting the child record and I want to find it's parent as well. I only have the id of the child record available.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$get_forum=$this->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".TBL_PREFIX."forums WHERE id=? OR id=?");
$get_forum->bindParam(array($forum_id,$forum["parent_id"]));
$get_forum->execute();
```

Comment: That completly misses what I am trying to do. I only know the forum_id I have no clue what it's parent id is until I get it out of the database. Therefore while I am doing the query I would like to somehow access that parent field and compare it to get the parent in the one query if possible.

Comment: Your question is using $forum["parent_id"] so i thought this is also the another id...anyways in this case there will need to call recursive function in you want to fetch data of one id for its nested records.

Comment: I get $forum["parent_id"] as a result of the first query which returns it. However I would like to combine those two queries into one.

Comment: That's what i am trying to say a recursive function will solve this to get the data of forum_id and data of its parent...Let me ask you one question.. Is there also a parent of parent of forum_id? IF yes then upto what level you want to fetch the data?

Comment: For now there is only 1 level of parent.

Comment: See my response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835230/where-to-return-value-from-a-recursive-function-in-php/9835572#comment12533745_9835572 to fetch records of child and parent as well. you will need to make changes in that query as per your need. HOPE THIS WILL WORK FOR YOU.

Comment: I don't believe I need recursion unless I have more then 1 level of parent.